# Переход между элементами с пропуском если есть class (hide)

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. Как сделать так что бы если в элементе li существует class `hide` тогда этот элемент пропустить и перейти к другому.

```js
// Функция вызывается при нажатие на любую клавишу клавиотуры
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 // Переменная которая содержит активный элемент
    var input = document.querySelector('.menu').querySelector("li.active");
    // Кнопка которая жаната
    var key = event.keyCode;

    // Принудительно обновляем boolean - true
    var needFocusElement = true;

    // Оператор try обробатывает условие и выберает тот вариант который заложин
    try {
  switch (key) {
      case 38: // стрелка вверх
          needFocusElement = input.previousElementSibling;
          break;
      case 40: // стрелка вниз
          needFocusElement = input.nextElementSibling;
          break;
      default:
       // если не нашло кнопку присваеваем boolean - false
          needFocusElement = false;
  }
    } catch (e) {needFocusElement = false;}

    // Если переменая == false заканчиваем функцию
    if (!needFocusElement) return;

    // Удаляем старый class
    input.classList.remove('active');

    // Создаем новый class элементу
    needFocusElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="active">DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li class="hide">Hide - DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
 <li>DarkWeb</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Организовываете цикл с условием `needFocusElement && needFocusElement.classList.contains('hide')`

```js
// Функция вызывается при нажатие на любую клавишу клавиатуры
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  // Переменная которая содержит активный элемент
  var input = document.querySelector('.menu').querySelector("li.active");
  var needFocusElement = input;
  // Кнопка которая нажата
  var key = event.keyCode;

  do {
    switch (key) {
      case 38: // стрелка вверх
        needFocusElement = needFocusElement.previousElementSibling;
        break;
      case 40: // стрелка вниз
        needFocusElement = needFocusElement.nextElementSibling;
        break;
      default:
        // если не нашло кнопку присваиваем null
        needFocusElement = null;
    }
  // Выполняем цикл пока находится элемент и он содержит класс hide
  } while (needFocusElement && needFocusElement.classList.contains('hide'))

  // Если переменная == null заканчиваем функцию
  if (!needFocusElement) return;

  // Удаляем старый class
  input.classList.remove('active');

  // Создаем новый class элементу
  needFocusElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active">DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li class="hide">Hide - DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
  <li>DarkWeb</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое я парился над этой фигнёй около недели.

Comment: @ПолосатыйТигр Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный